# Save xaml code folding in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I prefer to collapse some areas of the code. However, opening the editor again I get all the open areas that I closed earlier. Look at the screenshots (1 - fold code, 2 - opened Visual Studio again):

[image: rolled up the code]

[image: opened Visual Studio again]

Visual Studio XAML editor does not remember my preferences, unlike the Visual Studio C# editor. I did not find in the settings that would not allow to keep folding.

**Is there a possibility (possibly plugins) for saving code folding?**
Thanks